# Replicate the autocorrelation values in R

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to replicate the values of the `acf()` function in R but when I run my code, it is not able to make it.

```
x=rnorm(180)
meanT=mean(x)
r=vector();
n=length(x);
L=vector();
for (k in 0:10){
  for (i in 1:(n-k)){
    X1=x[1:(n-k)]
    X2=x[(1+k):n]
    r[k+1]=sum((X1-meanT)*(X2-meanT))/(sqrt(sum((X1-meanT)^2))*sqrt(sum((X2-meanT)^2)))
  }
  L[k+1]=k
}

round(r,3)
acf(x,10,plot=F)
```

Any idea why this discrepancy appears in the results?. Is the problem in the loop?

Comment: use `set.seed(1)` or `set.seed(anynumber)` before generating random number and then run both

Comment: @user227710, it doesn't solve the problem. The problem persists

Comment: He is storing his random numbers in the vector `x`. So the seed is not the problem here. @Erincon You have this loop going over `i` but `i` is nowhere used as far as I can see...

Comment: Type `acf` in the console to understand how it is computed in `R`.

Comment: Where exactly is the discrepancy? The results are perfectly reproducible once you use `set.seed()`

Comment: @MaratTalipov, the result of my code for  `10` lags is:
 `[1.000  0.007  0.035 -0.007 -0.008  0.021 -0.019  0.094 -0.087  0.114 -0.029]` 

and the `acf()` result is :

`[1.000  0.007  0.035 -0.007 -0.008  0.020 -0.019  0.091 -0.084  0.110 -0.027]`. You see the last values?

Comment: @cryo111 See here: `for (i in 1:(n-k))`

Comment: @user227710 `acf` uses C code.

Comment: `acf` function calls for `C_acf` function which is inside a dll;  `getAnywhere(C_acf)`

Comment: @user227710 I don't really understand very well the R routine

Answer (score 1):

The `acf` does not use the usual correlation formula. See http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35c.htm. Below a function for what `acf` is probably doing.

```
myacf=function(x,lag.max=10){
  x <- as.matrix(as.ts(x))
  x <- sweep(x, 2, colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE), check.margin = FALSE)
  n <- as.integer(nrow(x))
  macf=as.numeric(sapply(0:lag.max,function(k)
                  sum(x[1:(n-k)]*x[(k+1):n])/sum(x^2)))
  names(macf)=0:lag.max;
  macf
}

## Examples from Venables & Ripley ?acf
# require(graphics)

rbind(acf(lh,10,plot=F)$acf,
myacf(lh,10))
```